# "Shifts" from what/where to rebuilding?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

The headline is:

"South Africa’s Government Shifts to Rebuilding After Disastrous Flooding"

the source is:

"https://www.nytimes.com/live/2022/04/19/world/south-africa-floods"

if it shifts, it shifts FROM something right? I read throught the whole text and cound not figure out FROM what the government shifts to Rebuilding? what could "shift" implies?

Comment: It is probably shifting from "rescue" to "rebuilding".  But this isn't given in the text.  It is just that when there is "disastrous flooding" the first thing you need to do is rescue people.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that it doesn't say. Yes, "to" implies "from," but it doesn't have to specify it. If, in a car, I "shift to neutral," I may have shifted *from* reverse or any other gear. Headlines don't tell the whole story; the story under them hopefully does!

Answer (score 0):

"shifts" reveals how the government was preoccupied with other issues initially, and "shifted **to**" rebuilding its country after the floods. To elaborate further, "shifted to" means that the government is *focusing its attention* on rebuilding the affected areas of the floods.

They "shifted to" not "shifted from", as shifted from means the government was rebuilding before the floods, shifted to means they started to rebuild.

Comment: Don't you think using the word "shifts" logically implies shift from? shift implies a change right? from from what? you have to change from a previous thing don't you agree